# Sonata Media: The file could not be found

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata, sonatype

I'm trying to attach an image to an Entity but when I submit the form, an error is displayed saying: The file could not be found.

Here is my code to build the form:

```
$builder
    ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'Email'))
    ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Name'))
    ->add('image', 'sonata_media_type', array('label' => 'Image', 'provider' => 'sonata.media.provider.image', 'context'  => 'default'))
;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: error is when you add a file on a form? if not, add `'require' => false` to array of options for `image` field.

Comment: I have added that and it still doesn't work

Comment: Try to pass a data_class as well? `'data_class' => 'Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media'`

Comment: this is due to that you have set the file validation rule in validation class.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to 'link' your Entity to the SonataMediaBundle :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="image", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $image;
```

And then in your Admin, in the `configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)` :

```
->add('image', 'sonata_type_model_list', array('label' => 'Image', 'required' => false)))
```

In my projects, I've made it like that :)